# Pandas dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this csv:

| message | reported_agents |
| --- | --- |
| Missing status flag was removed | host1 |
| Missing status flag was raised | host1 |
| Missing status flag was removed | host2 |
| Missing status flag was raised | host2 |
| Missing status flag was raised | host3 |

I need to get this

| Host | total messages | Missing flag remove | Missing flag raised |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| host1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| host2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| host3 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

This is what I did but it doesn't show what I need. Thank you for your help

```
def load_data():
    event = pd.read_csv("events.csv")
    return event
data = load_data()

def GCmissing(data):
        x=data.groupby('hosts')['message'].value_counts()
```

Comment: Please post you input and output data as text, or better code that can be copied to get the dataframes directly.

Answer (score 3):

Use `pandas.crosstab` and then sum along columns for totals:

```
out_df = pd.crosstab(index = df['reported_agents'], columns = df['message'])
out_df['total_messages'] = out_df.sum(axis = 1)
```

Output:

```
reported_agents Missing status flag was raised  Missing status flag was removed total_messages
host1           1                               1                               2
host2           1                               1                               2
host3           1                               0                               1
```